# making vsftpd listen on a specific hostname

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

Is there a way to restrict which hostname(s) vsftpd listens to? I know it can be limited to listening on a particular IP and it fcan be limited by remote ip/hostname, but I wonder if listening only on a specific subdomain or something like that is possible? I'm on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the FTP protocol does not specifically include the server hostname in requests, this is probably not possible.

Comment: +1 The FTP protocol has no equivalent to HTTP's `Host:` header.

Comment: FTP now has a `HOST` command; see [RFC 7151](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7151).